# can't receive external mail

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exchange, smtp, email-server

Problem with the exchange 2003 server at our company
users can send and receive mail from and to each other.
receiving external mail (ex. from hotmail) doesn't work, sending to an external mail addres does work.

I should mention we did do a DNS transfer yesterday

Comment: Test your email server here: http://mxtoolbox.com/index.aspx

Comment: During this DNS transfer, did the MX record for your domain get transferred and correctly configured?

Comment: yes I phoned our provider and he checked our records, they were transfered correctly

Comment: could there be some sort of delay on this?

Comment: I tested on a site called hq42 and got this
`code`sending MAIL FROM tester@IP.IP.IP.IP response: 550 5.1.0 domain literals not allowed Your server may not configured to accept "domain literals". Refusal of "domain literals" like tester@IP.IP.IP.IP is a violation of RFC-822 Section 6.2.3 sending: MAIL FROM: postmaster@smtp.telenet-ops.be response: 250 2.1.0 sender ok sending: RCPT TO mymail@domain.be response: 550 5.1.1 recipient rejected: Relay access denied sending: QUIT Closing socket...socket closed `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error regarding "domain literals" comes from the configuration of your mailserver. I imagine that this was intentional and you don't ever expect mail to be sent to user@ip.ip.ip.ip anyway. It is obvious that your mailserver is talking.

Your provider is simultaneously the right and wrong person to verify your records. Assuming you use their servers, what they see is the most up-to-date information. It is likely that older information is cached in other places, or the chain pointing to your server is incomplete -- major domain servers might not be pointing to your nameserver, for example.

To test that the mailserver is acting correctly while the DNS system isn't, I suggest putting a hosts entry on a mailserver and then sending mail from that. Otherwise, do some directed-digging of DNS records: `dig example.com @10.1.2.3`. Check for all the different types of records you need along the chain (NS @ a .com server, A and MX at your server...).

Comment: I think the server is fine. so I should just wait till the caches get updated?

Comment: I think you should verify. It may be a cache issue, or it may be a bad update. Get access to an external box (ramp up an Amazon EC2 instance for .20 cents an hour or something) and ensure that things are behaving as expected.

Answer (score 1):

What DNS changes did you make?

This is likely an issue with the changed records not being correct - you'll need to verify that `MX` records exist for the domain, and that they point to valid `A` records for the SMTP server(s).

Comment: I tested on a site called hq42 and got this 

sending: MAIL FROM tester@IP.IP.IP.IP
response: 550 5.1.0 domain literals not allowed

Your server may not configured to accept "domain literals".
Refusal of "domain literals" like tester@IP.IP.IP.IP is a violation of RFC-822 Section 6.2.3

sending: MAIL FROM: postmaster@smtp.telenet-ops.be
response: 250 2.1.0 sender ok

sending: RCPT TO mymail@domain.be
response: 550 5.1.1 recipient rejected: Relay access denied

sending: QUIT
Closing socket...socket closed

Comment: "Relay access denied" means that your server is rejecting the message.  Did your DNS name actually change, instead of just moving the same name to a new provider?  Or, have permissions settings been modified recently on your SMTP receive connector?